# Add syntax highlighting for [thymeleaf] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The [thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thymeleaf) tag needs HTML syntax highlighting applied by default. It's an HTML template engine. Right now all the questions and answers are unnecessarily difficult to read with no syntax highlighting whatsoever.

The [syntax highlighting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/179419) requests that:

> If a language that could be applied to a tag is already on the list but not used on Stack Exchange, please raise a feature request...

HTML is on the list of languages already deployed from Prettify.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), *`If you feel there should be changes, post your diffs as answers.`*

Comment: @Draco18s, thanks, but that thread is locked.

Comment: Whoops, hadn't noticed. Also you can use the language overrides. `<!-- language: html -->` (for one block) or `<!-- language-all: html -->` (for all code blocks in the post).

Comment: I also agree, thymeleaf needs HTML syntax highlighting.